# Android FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack confusion

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I was studying Fragments and got little confused on differentiating `FragmentTransaction.replace(id, fragment, tag)` and `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag)` calls. Lets say that my current fragment is **FragmentA** and then I loaded **FragmentB**. I want that in future, when I need to load **FragmentA**, I don't have to reload it. Just load the old one in old state. I used the following code segment:

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragmentB, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    View fragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(fragmentContainer.getId(), fragmentB, tag);

    ft.addToBackStack(tag);

    ft.commit();
}
```

Now I am confused, where should I add the string tag? In `replace()` or in `addToBackStack()` or in both calls? Can you explain the difference between these two tag places?

Answer (score 7):

> Can you explain the difference between these two tag places?

The documentation for [`addToBackStack`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29) is pretty clear:

> An optional name for this back stack state, or null.

While for [`replace`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Optional tag name for the fragment, to later retrieve the fragment
>   with FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String).

So these two parameters are independent, one identifies the back stack, while the other identifies the fragment within `Activity's FragmentManager`.

Your code seems correct from this point of view, just that I would not search the `fragmentContainer` view by its id, only to use then its id for replacing the fragment. Make it simpler:

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragmentB, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB, tag);

    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    ft.commit();
}
```

In case you don't need to identify this back stack later on, pass null for `addToBackStack`. At least I'm always doing it.

Answer (score 6):

In this example you don't need to add tags as identification.
Just do:

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragmentB);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

The tag as identification is commonly used when you want to add a fragment without a UI.

Comment: but in future if I have added multiple fragments to stack and want to load a particular fragment then what?

Comment: Pass a Fragment `TAG` to be able to identify the fragment When adding it to the BackStack:

`.addToBackStack(YourFragment.TAG);`

So you can check if a Fragment is already in the BackStack using: 

`getFragmentMangager().findFragmentByTag(YourFragment.TAG);`

Comment: ft.addToBackStack(null); what is the purpose of this line of code?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html shows us that addToBackStack(null) will ensure that the transaction is also saved to the backstack. Optionally, you can use a name for this backstack state.

Comment: What is "a name for this backstack state"? I mean, what is the purpose of the "backstack state"?

Answer (score 4):

Passing null to addtoBackStack(null) means adding the fragment in the Fragment Stack but not adding any TAG which could be further use to identify the particular fragment in a stack before adding again.

```
    .addToBackStack(null);
```

But passing TAG to addToBackStack helps in identifying the fragment in Fragment stack by TAG.
Like

```
.addToBackStack(FragmentName.TAG);
```

Now we can check the fragment before adding it to the Stack :

```
 getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SettingsFragment.TAG);
```

This will return null if the Fragment is not already added.

Answer (score 2):

Param passed to `addToBackStack()` can be used to retrieve the whole BackStackEntry object, not just a single fragment. In order to set the fragment tag, consider using 3-param versions of add(int, Fragment, String) and replace(int, Fragment, String)

Prior to adding the Fragment you will be able to check if this Fragment is already in the backstack using :

```
 getFragmentMangager().findFragmentByTag(SettingsFragment.TAG);
```

This will return `null` if the `Fragment` is not already added.