# Call Fragment Activity error Unable to instantiate activity. cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment, adapter

I need help , for onclick on recyclerview and open new fragment activity, im clicked in item list close app and logcat error is:  Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.divemex/com.example.works.Pem}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.works.Pem cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

My code adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final tramoView tramoView, final int i) {
        final TramoModel tramoModel = tramoList.get(i);
        tramoView.txtnombreMostrar.setText(tramoModel.getTramoName());
        tramoView.txtnombreMostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent =  new Intent(v.getContext(), Pem.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            } });
    }
```

My code class fragment:

```
public class Pem extends  Fragment {

    private TabAdapter adapter;
    private TabLayout tableLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs, container, false);

        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.request_orders_view_pager);
        tableLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.request_orders_tabs);

        adapter = new TabAdapter(getFragmentManager());
       // adapter = new TabAdapter(FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new fragment1(), "Tab 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new fragment2(), "Tab 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new fragment3(), "Tab 3");
        adapter.addFragment(new fragment4(), "Tab 4");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tableLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Error :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T4d4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deal with fragments like activities. One of `Intents` purpose is to start new activities, but not fragments.

You got an exception in below line of code, because you use an `Intent` to start a `Fragment` (as `Pem.class` is a fragment); and fragments can't start this way.

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(v.getContext(), Pem.class);
```

And this is obvious in the Exception you got
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.works.Pem cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Which indicates that it's not allowed to cast Pem.class to an Activity; that is because it doesn't extend `Activity` class or any of its sub-classes.

To solve this, either:

1. Make Pem.class an Activity by extending `AppCompatActivity` class
   (or any activity class), and replace the activity's callback methods
   instead of the fragment ones.
2. Or Make fragment transaction in the current activity and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782808/what-does-fragmentmanager-and-fragmenttransaction-exactly-do) you can find details

Answer (score 0):

You use this :
    Intent intent =  new Intent(v.getContext(), Pem.class);
    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

But `Pem` is a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`.

Comment: Which `XXXActivity` you want to jump,  the second param willbe the `XXXActivity.class` will be use.