# Handle back pressed of multiple fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

Hi Currently am developing application using fragments.Totally i have 15 fragments and loaded it in single Activity.While onBack Pressing on Each fragment will launch previous fragment.I google about it and also i got answers for it.but i just want to know which is more efficient way handle this.

Comment: **While onBack Pressing on Each fragment will perform different actions**. What actions? Back button will take you back to previous fragment. I also don't understand the need for 15 fragments hosted by 1 activity.

Comment: @Raghunandan previous fragments.

Comment: Each fragments are loaded on another fragment onClick

Comment: ok. What is that you are looking for?

Comment: add all fragment in `addToBackStack(null)` while transaction

Comment: http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/10/01/handling-back-button-press-inside-fragments/

Comment: i have an doubt if we are doing like this..While on serveral conditions(i.e)if GC removes the backstack how can we get it.

Comment: what this code can do:addToBackStack(null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `addToBackStack()`, the replace transaction is saved to the back stack so the user can reverse the transaction and bring back the previous fragment by pressing the Back button. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984950/what-is-the-meaning-of-addtobackstack-with-null-parameter)

If you add multiple changes to the transaction (such as another add() or remove()) and call `addToBackStack()`, then all changes applied before you call commit() are added to the back stack as a single transaction and the Back button will reverse them all together.

Just add this `transaction.addToBackStack(null);`

For more information you may visit [Handling back button press Inside Fragments](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/10/01/handling-back-button-press-inside-fragments/)