# Removing the Main activity from the Backstack?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a main activity (M) (host activity) and few full page size fragments (f1,f2,f3).
My main activity is a empty page and I am not showing anything into it.
When my app starts, I am showing fragment f1 by default.
But when I am pressing back button I am landing on white page of my main activity (M).
I don't want activity M in my backstack. How can I remove that?
I tried intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); before activity started, but it's not working also I tried finish(); after start activity but it is also not working. Any Idea?

I have a problem about removing Mainactivity from back stack ..

When i press back button from specific fragment it lead me to a white page "content main" of my main activity (M).

Comment: the question should be like how should I remove the first fragment opened from backStack on backPressed Method

Comment: please can you show the first screen shot when your app gets opened ? because from I am seeing your app opens a blank page at start! or something else! the question statement is VAGUE please be specific a little! thnx!

Comment: I changed "the first fragment opened from backStack"  by setting a specific fragment with  { displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_camera); } ... So the first things stack in "backStack" is Mainactivity .. i want to remove it there whene i press back from an fragment ..

Comment: so got it if you want  a back stack with your own style of code that you are using just see my answer I am gonna put ok? and hope that will help!

Comment: hope also .. thx @Rizwanatta

Comment: try the edited answer! please

Comment: No resolt .. the MainActivity "conten_main" still have "addToBackStack" and all fragment get replace with "content_frame"@Rizwanatta

Comment: check the edited version now

Comment: it overlapp fragments @Rizwanatta

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the fragment empty Activity M in the backstack,  don't add fragment f1 to the backstack in your fragment transaction.

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

More info :

- [addToBackStack docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String))
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22985052/794088

Comment: if i don't add fragment to to the backstack, all fragments get overlap ..@petey