# How can I go back to main activity from a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I successfully implemented a bottom navigation drawer and had used fragments. Now i can switch fragments from the drawer menu.
My problem here is that when I open an item from the drawer menu (example; About Developer), when the user clicks the back button it closes the app. Instead i want the user to return to the Main Activity from any fragment. Help me with this, I don't have much experience.

Here is my code;

***How i implement the nav drawer items using drawer adapter with a custom library(SlidingRootNav- https://github.com/yarolegovich/SlidingRootNav);***

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(int position) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (position == POS_DASHBOARD){

            slidingRootNav.closeMenu();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }

        else if (position == POS_ABOUT_APP){
            ((CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.root_view)).removeAllViews();

            AboutAppFragment aboutApp = new AboutAppFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, aboutApp);

            slidingRootNav.closeMenu();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
        else if (position == POS_ABOUT_DEVELOPERS){
            ((CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.root_view)).removeAllViews();

            AboutDeveloper aboutDeveloper = new AboutDeveloper();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, aboutDeveloper);

            slidingRootNav.closeMenu();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
        

    }
```

**Fragment Class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class AboutDeveloper extends Fragment  {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_developer,container, false);


        // Here I implemented a toolbar at the top for navigation purpose
        // but on clicking on the nav icon, the app closes, instead i want to return to the main activity

        Toolbar toolbar = root.findViewById(R.id.return_home);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back_24);
        toolbar.setTitle("About Developer");


        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        return root;

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `replace` use `add` for your transaction

Answer (score 0):

I think that because you have null in method addToBackStack

```
 transaction.addToBackStack(null)
```

Therefore you don't get the main activity when you click on the back button.

If you want to read more about how addToBackStack works, I recommend you to read this [What is the meaning of addToBackStack with null parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984950/what-is-the-meaning-of-addtobackstack-with-null-parameter)

Comment: passing null parameter in my addToBackStack method was not the issue.. Infact it is part of the solution, cos I needed it to keep count of active fragment. Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

After doing some diggings, I finally found a way around it. All I had to do was to add a tweak to my onBackPressed method from the main activity (HomeActivity.class in my case).

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        //Return to home activity from any active fragment
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        //To close nav drawer
        else if(slidingRootNav.isMenuOpened()){
            slidingRootNav.closeMenu();

        }
        else {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

    }
```

**NB** addToBackStack must be used during fragment transactions to keep count of when a fragment is active.
say `transaction.addToBackStack(null)`

And as for the top navigation in my Fragment class, all I did was to add an Intent that calls the home activity when the toolbar nav icon is clicked.

```
public class AboutDeveloper extends Fragment  {

    Intent intent;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_developer,container, false);


        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);

        Toolbar toolbar = root.findViewById(R.id.return_home);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_24);
        toolbar.setTitle("About Developer");
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
        return root;

    }


}
```

Thanks to those who gave their suggestions.