# Android scrollview keep scroll position after fragment transaction

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I want to keep scrollview scroll position of a fragment. This fragment (`HomeFragment.kt`) is one of several fragments within a fragment with bottom navigation (`DashboardFragment.kt`).

This is how `HomeFragment.kt` loaded (This is a snippet of `DashboardFragment.kt`)

```kotlin
    private fun loadHomeFragment() {

        homeFragment = HomeFragment()

        dashboardFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(
                android.R.animator.fade_in,
                android.R.animator.fade_out
            )
            .replace(R.id.content, homeFragment, "1")
            .commit()
    }
```

And this is the scrollview layout (This is a snippet of `HomeFragment.kt` layout) :

```xml
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/swipeBaseLayout">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/baseLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="32dp">

                    <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
                        android:id="@+id/carouselView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                        app:pageColor="#00000000"
                        app:pageTransformInterval="800"
                        app:radius="3dp"
                        app:slideInterval="5000"
                        app:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                        app:strokeWidth="1px" />


                    <RelativeLayout>
                       .....
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

As you can see, I already have an id for the scrollview. But every time this fragment loaded or navigated back from another fragment (From another fragment to **DashboardFragment.kt**) (I'm using navigation component), it'll start from the top.

Is there any way to keep scrollview even after the fragment transaction? If there's any detail I missed to point out, just let me know.

Comment: Since you are not adding transaction to back stack i think that's why it will not save the State. Is this the requirement without adding it to backstack ?

Comment: @ADM So... what should I use instead of `replace()` ?

Comment: I meant using [addTobackStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984950/what-is-the-meaning-of-addtobackstack-with-null-parameter) not changing `replace()`.

Comment: If you're using the Navigation Component, you shouldn't be using `beginTransaction()` at all. Which is it? Navigation Component or not?

Comment: Did you figure out what was the issue? @dimashermanto

Comment: My views are very complex, I have a nestedScrollView in a FragmentStateAdapter (main Fragment) which navigates to a secondary Fragment.
For some reason your question @dimashermanto helped me with the sentence "I already have an id for the scrollview." I placed an ID and the problem went away.
I am still concerned tho, I remember things where working a couple days ago, then I messed around with dataBinding dynamic visibility and I think this is what messed the saved state position.

Answer (score 1):

For more control on your backstack, you can have your custom stack and check there is only one instance of a fragment in the stack.
Also for your problem, you can hide other fragments that are on top of the stack:

```
   showFragment(Fragment homeFragment) {
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getFragments().size(); i++) {
        if (fragmentManager.getFragments().get(i) != homeFragment) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.getFragments().get(i));
        }
    }
    fragmentTransaction.show(homeFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```